# Copy-Item Not Creating All Directories

Tags: powershell, recursion, copy-item

I have a directory that I want to recursively copy to anoth location for processing.  It seems like the first directory is not getting created.  The part of the program that does the copy is below:

```
# Read the source files to convert.
$lAllFiles = Get-ChildItem $lSrc -Exclude $lExcludedFiles

# Remove excluded directories
foreach ( $lExclusion in $lAllExcludedDirectories ) {

    # If we have a wildcard use the -notlike operator to filter the list.
    # Otherwise use an -ne operator.
    if ( ($lExclusion -like '*' ) -or ($lExclusion -like '?' ) ) {
        $lAllFiles = [array]$lAllFiles -notlike $lExclusion
    } else {
        $lAllFiles = [array]$lAllFiles -ne $lExclusion
    }
}

# Start the log.
Start-Transcript -Path "$lJobLog"

# Copy the data to be converted to the conversion root.
ForEach ( $lFile in $lAllFiles ) {
    Copy-Item $lFile  $lCnv -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable +JobErrors -Verbose
}

.
.
.
```

When I compare the source and destination directories, it looks as though the first subdirectory is not created in the destination and the contents of the first sub directory are written to the destination.

As an example:

```
The Source:
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----          1/6/2013   9:30 AM            AP-LEDGER
d----         3/12/2014   9:28 AM            AP.DETAIL
d----         8/20/2014   9:33 PM            AR-LEDGER
d----          9/3/2011   9:58 AM            lost+found
-a---         5/13/2016   9:21 PM      32768 AP-BATCH-CTRL
-a---         5/13/2016   8:39 PM  291293184 AP-LEDGER-XREF
-a---         9/28/2015   3:14 PM    8425472 AP.JDE
-a---         5/13/2016   8:39 PM  150700032 AP.LINK
-a---          5/2/2016   3:30 PM      52224 AP.QUEUES
-a---         5/13/2016   8:17 PM  743018496 AP.SUSP
-a---         4/30/2016   9:11 PM   51222528 ARROLLARC
-a---         4/30/2016   9:11 PM  102404096 ARROLLFWD
-a---         5/14/2016   3:29 AM 1016950784 A_Pa
-a---         5/14/2016  12:37 AM  238280704 A_Ra
-a---         5/14/2016   3:16 AM   61423616 GL-CROSS
-a---         5/14/2016   3:16 AM  175235072 GL-INDEX
-a---         5/14/2016   3:16 AM   21512192 G_La
-a---         5/14/2016   3:16 AM  224661504 X_AP.SUSP
-a---         5/14/2016   3:29 AM  150089728 X_A_Pa
-a---         5/14/2016  12:37 AM   63578112 X_A_Ra
```

The Destination:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         5/26/2016  10:53 PM            AP.DETAIL
d----         5/26/2016  10:53 PM            AR-LEDGER
-a---         5/13/2016   8:38 PM 1073737728 dat001
-a---         5/13/2016   8:39 PM  682541056 dat002
-a---         5/13/2016   8:39 PM 1004023808 idx001
-a---         5/13/2016   8:37 PM   41234432 over001
```

Note the files in the directory should reside in the folder AP-LEDGER.
What is going on?

Does the -Recurse -Force not create the directories?

Comment: What's `$lFile` contain? What about `$lAllFiles`?

Comment: $lAllFiles Contains X:\acctng_ssd\AP-LEDGER
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.DETAIL
X:\acctng_ssd\AR-LEDGER
X:\acctng_ssd\AP-BATCH-CTRL
X:\acctng_ssd\AP-LEDGER-XREF
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.JDE
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.LINK
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.QUEUES
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.SUSP
X:\acctng_ssd\ARROLLARC
X:\acctng_ssd\ARROLLFWD
X:\acctng_ssd\A_Pa
X:\acctng_ssd\A_Ra
X:\acctng_ssd\GL-CROSS
X:\acctng_ssd\GL-INDEX
X:\acctng_ssd\G_La

Comment: $lAllFiles contains the following:                                         `X:\acctng_ssd\AP-LEDGER
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.DETAIL
X:\acctng_ssd\AR-LEDGER
X:\acctng_ssd\AP-BATCH-CTRL
X:\acctng_ssd\AP-LEDGER-XREF
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.JDE
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.LINK
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.QUEUES
X:\acctng_ssd\AP.SUSP
X:\acctng_ssd\ARROLLARC
X:\acctng_ssd\ARROLLFWD
X:\acctng_ssd\A_Pa
X:\acctng_ssd\A_Ra
X:\acctng_ssd\GL-CROSS
X:\acctng_ssd\GL-INDEX
X:\acctng_ssd\G_La`                                                                                  $lFile contains the object for to X:\acctng_ssd\AP-LEDGER

Comment: Does the destination directory exist before the first copy? I'm going to bet it doesn't. So the first copy copies `AP-LEDGER` *as* the destination and the rest copy in to the newly created folder. Try ensuring the destination exists first and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Copy-Item`, I've used something like this function to copy files/directories from one location to the next with exclusions.

```
Function Copy-Folder($Path,$DestinationPath,$Exclude = $exclude) {
    # Get all the files to copy
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Exclude $Exclude 
    # Copy files to destination folder. 
    foreach($file in $files) {      
        Copy-Item $file.FullName $DestinationPath -Recurse -Force
        $filename = $file.Name
        $copy = "$DestinationPath\$filename"
        Write-Host "Copied: $filename to $copy"
    }
}
```

You should also take a look at your logic for the removing excluded sub-directories